# How to make John the Ripper output example hashes for a given hash type?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper

Is it possible to make John the Ripper output example hashes for a given hash type given by the `--format=` option?

This is possible using Hashcat, but currently I look in John the Ripper's source code for example hashes, which is rather slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[The jumbo version of john](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper) has a `--list=format-details` option. By default, it outputs one record per hash type for all hash types, with tab-separated values of a variety of information about that hash type (maximum password length, long name, etc.). You can also specify a hash type.

So for a specific hash type:

```
$ john --list=format-details --format=descrypt | cut -f15
CCNf8Sbh3HDfQ
```

The plaintext can vary - for hash types that have minimum lengths, etc. or if a particular failure mode is being tested for. In this case:

```
CCNf8Sbh3HDfQ:U*U*U*U*
```